JavaFX answer doesn't show up
I am coding Hangman game with javaFX, somehow the code assumes all of my guesses are wrong and always considered a mistake even if it's correct. So the user ends up always losing. I think it has something to do with the while loop I am using to make sure all redundancy of any letter is dealt with (like in "banana" if the user enters "a", the currect progress should be displayed as "-a-a-a" instead of "-a----") but i don't know: here is my controller class as well as word, if you need any other classes let me know!

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Controller {

    //inject an element defined in fxml to controller!
    @FXML
    //pane is a form container
    private Pane man;
    @FXML
    private Pane base1;
    @FXML
    private Pane base2;
    @FXML
    private Pane base3;
    @FXML
    private Pane pole;
    @FXML
    private Pane rod;
    @FXML
    private Pane rope1;
    @FXML
    private Pane rope2;
    @FXML
    private Text text;
    @FXML
    private Pane buttons;
    @FXML
    private Text winStatus;
    @FXML
    private Text realWord;

    private int mistakes;
    private int correct;
    
    private String[] table;
    private String word;
    private String category;
    private List<String> myLetters;
    private List<String> answer;

    public Controller(){
    }

    public void initialize() {
        base1.setVisible(false);
        base2.setVisible(false);
        base3.setVisible(false);
        pole.setVisible(false);
        rod.setVisible(false);
        rope1.setVisible(false);
        rope2.setVisible(false);
        man.setVisible(false);
        buttons.setDisable(false);
        
        mistakes=0;
        correct=0;
        
        table = Words.getRandomWord(2);
        word=table[1];
        category=table[0];
        
        myLetters = Arrays.asList(word.split(""));
        answer = Arrays.asList(new String[myLetters.size()*2]);
        
        for(int i=0; i<myLetters.size()*2; i++){
            if(i%2==0){
                answer.set(i, "_");
            }else{
                answer.set(i, " ");
            }
        }
        String res = String.join("", answer);
        text.setText(res);
        
        //hide winstatus and realword in case of a new game! 
        winStatus.setText("");
        realWord.setText("");
    }

    //when do i call for u ?when the event i declared happened!
    public void onClick(ActionEvent event){
        //getText return string not char
        String letter = ((Button)event.getSource()).getText();
        ((Button) event.getSource()).setDisable(true);
        
        if(myLetters.contains(letter)){
            correct++;
            int letterIndex = myLetters.indexOf(letter);
            while (letterIndex != -1) {
                myLetters.set(letterIndex, "*");
                answer.set(letterIndex*2, letter);
                letterIndex = myLetters.indexOf(letter);
                String res = String.join("", answer);
                text.setText(res);
            }
            
            if(correct==word.length()){
                winStatus.setText("You Win!");
                buttons.setDisable(true);
            }
        }
        else{
            mistakes++;
            if(mistakes ==1)       base1.setVisible(true);
            else if (mistakes ==2) base2.setVisible(true);
            else if (mistakes ==3) base3.setVisible(true);
            else if (mistakes ==4) pole.setVisible(true);
            else if (mistakes ==5) rod.setVisible(true);
            else if (mistakes ==6) rope1.setVisible(true);
            else if (mistakes ==7) rope2.setVisible(true);
            else if (mistakes ==8){
                rope2.setVisible(false); //7bal lmachan9a around the neck 
                man.setVisible(true);//sad face+body
                winStatus.setText("You Lose!");
                realWord.setText("The actual word was " + word);
                buttons.setDisable(true);
            }
        }
    }

    public void newGame(){
        //i don't get what does the loops does
        //why enable here and enable in initialize?
        for(int i=0; i<26; i++){
            buttons.getChildren().get(i).setDisable(false);
        }
        initialize();
    }


}
package sample;

import java.util.Random;

public class Words{
    
       
    public static String[] getRandomWord(int languageChoice) {
        
        String[] fruits = {"strawberry", "banana", "orange", "apple", "cherry", "peach", "kiwi", "lemon", "grape", "mango"};
        String[] countries = {"tunisia", "spain", "japan", "qatar", "greece", "palestine", "italy", "canada", "germany", "china"};
        String[] animals = {"shark", "wolf", "cat", "cow", "snake", "horse", "dog", "lion", "rabbit", "zebra"};
        String[] languages = {"arabic", "korean", "english", "russian", "turkish", "hindi", "spanish", "french", "german", "chinese"};
        String[] occupations = {"doctor", "engineer", "teacher", "baker", "clown", "pilot", "lawyer", "chef", "nurse", "police"};

        String[] fruit = {"fraise", "bananes", "orange", "pomme", "cerise", "pêche", "kiwi", "citron", "raisin", "mangue"};
        String[] pays = {"tunisie", "espagne", "japon", "qatar", "grèce", "palestine", "italie", "canada", "allemagne", "chine"};
        String[] animaux = {"requin", "loup", "chat", "vache", "serpent", "cheval", "chien", "lion", "lapin", "zèbre"};
        String[] langues = {"arabe", "coréen", "anglais", "russe", "turc", "hindi", "espagnol", "français", "allemand", "chinois"};
        String[] professions = {"médecin", "ingénieur", "enseignant", "boulanger", "clown", "pilote", "avocat", "chef", "infirmier", "police"};
        
        String category=null;
        String word=null;      
        int categoryIndex = new Random().nextInt(5)+1; 

        if (languageChoice == 2) {
            switch (categoryIndex) {
                case 1:
                    category = "fruits";
                    word = fruits[new Random().nextInt(fruits.length)];
                    break;
                case 2:
                    category = "countries";
                    word = countries[new Random().nextInt(countries.length)];
                    break;
                case 3:
                    category = "animals";
                    word = animals[new Random().nextInt(animals.length)];
                    break;
                case 4:
                    category = "languages";
                    word = languages[new Random().nextInt(languages.length)];
                    break;
                case 5:
                    category = "occupations";
                    word = occupations[new Random().nextInt(occupations.length)];
                    break;
            }
        } 
        else {
            switch (categoryIndex) {
                case 1:
                    category = "fruits";
                    word = fruit[new Random().nextInt(fruit.length)];
                    break;
                case 2:
                    category = "pays";
                    word = pays[new Random().nextInt(pays.length)];
                    break;
                case 3:
                    category = "animaux";
                    word = animaux[new Random().nextInt(animaux.length)];
                    break;
                case 4:
                    category = "langues";
                    word = langues[new Random().nextInt(langues.length)];
                    break;
                case 5:
                    category = "professions";
                    word = professions[new Random().nextInt(professions.length)];
                    break;
            }
        }

        return new String[]{category, word};
    }
} ```


This is basically a code dump and finds my issue. No one wants to sort through partial code trying to find an issue. Here are some pointers. Create some static methods in Words that do things like Find the indexes of all the current letters in the current word. You can also do something similar to generate the initial String.

@SedJ601 what do people want then?

https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

This is not a GUI app, but hopefully, it can demonstrate some of the ideas that I think programmers should use when programming. A lot of the ideas have to do with breaking things into smaller tasks. This helps in finding bugs, IMO.

Create static helper methods to help do operations on a class. Example: the Word class needs to know the index of each character in a word. This example uses getIndexOfCharacters to find the index of every character in the current word and returns that info in a Map. There are other static Word methods to aid in getting information related to the Word class. I would also have the AI as a separate class and a general helper utility if needed. I didn't do either for this example.

Try to find the best data structure for the job. In this example, I use Map, List, and Set for different reasons related to the job they will do.

As it relates to a lot of games, think about things in terms of states. I didn't do a great job here, but the board can be seen as the state before and after a guess.


I hope some of these ideas help. Good luck coding!
Main
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 *
 * @author sedj601
 */
public class Mavenproject24 {   
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        String someString = Word.getRandomWord();
        StringBuilder board = new StringBuilder(Word.createInitialBoard(someString));        
        //System.out.println("Board: " + board.toString());
        
        Map<Character, List<Integer>> characterIndexes = Word.getIndexOfCharacters(someString);
        //printMap(characterIndexes);
        
        Set<Character> rightGuesses = createWinSet(someString);//keeps up with correct guesses.
        List<Character> wrongGuesses = new ArrayList(); //Keep up with the number of incorrect guesses.
        
        
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<Character> choices = createAiPlayerChoices();
        
        for(int i = 0; i < choices.size(); i++)
        {
            char aiGuess = choices.get(i);
            
            if(characterIndexes.containsKey(aiGuess))
            {
                //Update the board
                characterIndexes.get(aiGuess).forEach((index) -> {
                    board.setCharAt(Word.convertToBoardIndex(index), aiGuess);
                });
                //Remove char from correctGuesses map; 
                rightGuesses.remove(aiGuess);
                
            }
            else
            {
                //Add Character to wrong guess list.
                wrongGuesses.add(aiGuess);
            }            
            
            System.out.println("AI Guess " + i + " - " + aiGuess + ": " + board.toString());
            checkForWinOrLose(wrongGuesses, rightGuesses);
            input.nextLine();//Press enter to take another guess            
        }
    }
    
    static public List<Character> createAiPlayerChoices()
    {
        List<Character> choices = new ArrayList();
        
        String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        for(int i = 0; i < alphabet.length(); i++)
        {
            choices.add(alphabet.charAt(i));
        }
        Collections.shuffle(choices);
        
        return choices;
    }
    
    static public void checkForWinOrLose(List<Character> wrongGuesses, Set<Character> rightGuesses)
    {
        int numOfAppendages = 20;
        if(wrongGuesses.size() >= numOfAppendages)
        {
            System.out.println("Game Over: You lose!");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else if(rightGuesses.isEmpty())
        {
            System.out.println("Game Over: You Win!");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Keep going! No win or lose!");
        }      
    }       
           
    static public Set<Character> createWinSet(String word)
    {
        Set<Character> winSet = new HashSet();
        for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
        {
            winSet.add(word.charAt(i));
        }
        
        return winSet;
    }
    
    //    static public void printMap(Map<Character, List<Integer>> inputMap)
//    {
//        for (Map.Entry<Character, List<Integer>> entry : inputMap.entrySet()) {
//            System.out.print(entry.getKey());
//            entry.getValue().forEach((t) -> {
//                System.out.print("\t" + t);
//            });
//            System.out.println("");
//        }
//    }
}

Word
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class Word
{
    public static String getRandomWord()
    {
        return "banana";
    }
    
    static public String createInitialBoard(String word)
    {
        String board = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < 2 * word.length() - 1; i++)
        {
            if(i % 2 == 1)
            {
                board += "-";
            }
            else
            {
                board += "_";
            }
            
        }
        
        return board;
    }    
    
    static public int convertToBoardIndex(int stringIndex)
    {
        return 2 * stringIndex;
    }  
    
    static public Map<Character, List<Integer>> getIndexOfCharacters(String word)
    {
        Map<Character, List<Integer>> indexes = new HashMap();
        
        for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
        {
            if(!indexes.containsKey(word.charAt(i)))
            {
                List<Integer> newList = new ArrayList();
                newList.add(i);
                indexes.put(word.charAt(i), newList);
            }
            else
            {
                indexes.get(word.charAt(i)).add(i);
            }
        }
        
        return indexes;
    }
}


Note: If you want to increase the chance of the AI losing, make numOfAppendages = a low number. Also, this code may have issues.

Thank you all for your help: I found the problem in case anyone is interested. It's silly hahaha. My Controller button value is returning an uppercase letter and I'm comparing it to lowercase ones, so the letters were never found!
